# What does 乐群 (lèqún) mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Among the many banners for new students at Nankai Uni is this one:

[image: 爱国 敬业 创新 乐群]

It says:

> 爱国 敬业 创新 乐群
>   <sub>Àiguó jìngyè chuàngxīn lèqún</sub>

The first three I can translate:

- [爱国](http://dict.cn/%E7%88%B1%E5%9B%BD) (àiguó） = patriotism (literally "love country")
- [敬业](http://dict.cn/%E6%95%AC%E4%B8%9A) (jìngyè) = dedication to one's job
- [创新](http://dict.cn/%E5%88%9B%E6%96%B0) (chuàngxīn） = innovation

But the fourth one doesn't appear on dict.cn.  (And I think I've managed to identify the hanzi characters here.)

**Question**: What does 乐群 (lèqún) mean?

If we break it down:

- [乐](http://dict.cn/%E4%B9%90) (lè) = happy
- [群](http://dict.cn/%E7%BE%A4) (qún) = group

So I guess it means something like "happy group", which sounds a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%95%AC%E4%B8%9A%E4%B9%90%E7%BE%A4) gives the origin of this expression as from 《礼记·学记》, and explains 乐群 as:

> 乐群：乐于与好朋友相处

Willing to socialize with friends.

Comment: 看来室友投毒这事震惊不小啊。^_^

Answer (score 1):

乐 here means 喜欢, like, enjoy

群 means group

乐群 means enjoy group-living, willing to go well with others, and that kind of idea.